# Ubuntu Terminal Command "cd -" makes a Loop!

Tags: command-line, bash

Well I am fairly new in Ubuntu world. New to Terminal too. Asfaik I can use the command `cd -` to go back to the previous directory. Now lets say I am in a directory which is `home/dir1/dir2/dir3/mydir`. Well now if I write `cd -` terminal will send me to `dir3` but if I want to go to `dir2` and I write `cd -` terminal takes me to `mydir` again! And then if I write `cd -` again terminal takes me to `dir3` as expected. It means I fall into a loop. Can anyone tell me how can....

1. Directly go to `dir2` from `mydir`?
2. Browse `mydir` to `dir3` and then `dir3` to `dir2` without falling into any loop?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to go 1 level higher in directory tree, you do

```
cd ..
```

So if you are at `home/dir1/dir2/dir3/mydir` this command will take you to `home/dir1/dir2/dir3`.

Same command another time to `home/dir1/dir2`.

If you want to go from `home/dir1/dir2/dir3/mydir` to `home/dir1/dir2`, you do

```
cd ../..
```

The command you tried `cd -` takes you to previous directory.